# How to test Notifications in Chrome with Testcafé and Chrome Native Automation (cdp)?

Tags: testcafe, cdp

We want to test Notifications (send with Firebase) in Chrome with Testcafé and Chrome Native Automation (cdp).
When a user starts the browser the question comes to enable notifications for this site.
Is there a way to automate this setting, or can we start Chrome with this enabled by default?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Browser.grantPermissions](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-grantPermissions) to configure the notification permissions for specific origin.

Comment: Thank you Oleksii for this tip, I got this to work with this code:

    const testrun = t.testRun;
    const browserId = testrun.browserConnection.id;
    const cdpClient = testrun.browserConnection.provider.plugin.openedBrowsers[browserId].nativeAutomation._client;
    await cdpClient.Browser.grantPermissions({
      permissions: ["notifications"],
      origin: "https://my-internal-site-url",
    });


Although this setting now looks fine during the test still no Firebase notifications are received. I will investigate this further.

Comment: I tried further, this code does the same:

  ```const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface");
  const cdpClient = await CDP();
  await cdpClient.Browser.grantPermissions({
    permissions: ["notifications"],
    origin: "my-internal-site-url",
  });```

Running TestCafe with native automation or not, there are no notifications received by the browser.
Next step is to have a system policy set for notifications, the CDP-code would than not be necessary. See what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface");
  const cdpClient = await CDP();
  await cdpClient.Browser.grantPermissions({
    permissions: ["notifications"],
    origin: url,
  });
```

Comment: Hi EdwinR, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will improve its long-term value. Thanks